# ui.bootstrap angular alert close issue

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular, trying to figure out how the bootstrap alert work in angular

in regular bootstrap something below gives the alert message and it gets closed when clicked on X

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
  <strong>Well Done!</strong> Your action is successful.       
</div>
```

All the examples i saw are using AlertCtrl and needed to code the array of alerts and need to code a method to splice the array when close button clicked.

In a Single Page Application, If i want to show only one success alert message when user perform an action

```
.directive('myCustomAlert', function(){
  return {
    restrict:'E',
    template:'<alert type="success" close="close">{{model-dynamic-msg}}</alert>',
    controller:'MyCtrl'
}
```

since the close attribute present the alert is displaying well. when added

```
<my-custom-alert></my-custom-alert>
```

but not able to dismiss the message when clicked on x

here is the plunker :  http://plnkr.co/edit/NfEleLc0Q6pzjirb3DCg

am i missing to include any library.

Comment: bootstrap alert close uses this attribute to handle close "data-dismiss="alert"..take a look on your template..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this on you include script tags:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"</script>
```

UPDATED:

Like what **@Sunil D.** mentioned. You don't have to create your own bootstrap alert directive if you are using UI-Bootstrap, it is the purpose of the ui-project. If you look on ui-bootstrap docs about alert, you can see they are using ng-repeat to render alerts and handle remove alerts by just removing the index of the generated alert.

Comment: The OP is using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), so they do not need to load the javascript from the Bootstrap project ;)

Comment: @SunilD. yes but not loading "ui-bootstrap-0.11.0.min.js".. only "ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"..I think so..

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you may want to edit your answer. In the answer, you are referring to the bootstrap javascript file, but in your comment above you then reference the ui-bootstrap javascript file.

Comment: @Darryl_Coder your code is working great.if you can make the change i would accept the answer

Comment: @SunilD if i remove the bootstrap.min.js then the close not working

Comment: if you want to make a directive for alert, you may use traditional bootstrap file. if you want the ui-bootstrap, there is already a directive for alert. they use object array to show and close alerts..

Comment: @CodeQ, you should take a closer look at the Alert example on the UI Bootstrap site. They use an ng-repeat to render the Alert. Then they use a function that splices the closed Alert from the array from the array used by ng-repeat.  I was leaving work, so I couldn't post an answer and on a phone now)

Comment: You shouldn't have to use the Bootstrap JavaScript to do this, that's the whole point of the Angular UI Bootstrap project :)

Comment: @SunilD I am still not clear, i understand if i have a site wide Alert placer that can be populated to an array of alert messages and splice when dismissed. what if i need the one alert multiple places in the app.

Comment: @CodeQ if you want site wide alert for that, you can write your own implementation using angular services to make it available in all your app. Here is a simple custom alert service that I wrote for my app for site wide alert.

https://gist.github.com/darryldecode/456db30246c633bf3ab8

then you can inject the service on your controller and use it like so:

GlobalLoaderService.show("some alert message","info");
GlobalLoaderService.hide();

or chain also:

GlobalLoaderService.show("some alert message","info").hide();

Comment: I'm using ui-bootstrap bower component. I've linked both ui-bootsrap.min.js & ui-bootstrap-tpl.min.js in my project. I can show the alert but the close button is not working. Should I define the function closeAlert() in my controller or it's written within the ui-bootsrap file.

Answer (score 0):

it can be as simple as this, without directive or controller:

```
<alert type="danger" close="bCloseAlert=1" ng-hide="bCloseAlert">i'm alert</alert>
```